# Can we have gold centralised over the party in Baldurs Gate 3?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

I noticed that in Baldurs Gate 3 the gold you own actually just exists as stacks of coins in your inventory. It also seems to stack rather arbitrarily, with my main char sometimes having 2-3 stacks of gold spread throughout the other items.

Furthermore, your other companions *also* have their own stacks of gold in *their* inventory.

As of now gold just clutters inventory space and is a general mess to deal with, since from what I gathered it doesn't matter who carries the gold when paying for items in shops...

Is there any way to have the gold "centralised" over all characters, i.e. just one stack/value that encompasses all the gold that any of my party members have?

Answer (score 11):

### Why no pool?

#### Multiplayer

BG3 is, from its base, built in such a way that multiplayer introduces the lowest number of changes needed to the game. Managing loot for a party of players separate from one another in different inventories is a direct result of this - it just needs to block access to a character's inventory for non-privileged players. This includes gold and makes separate purchasing between different Characters - especially different player-controlled ones - easier to control.

Gold as a single *global* resource does not work neatly with multiplayer, especially as gold on other player's characters is not taken into account when in a shop.

#### Weight

There's another limiter: each coin has a weight associated with it, and you might want to distribute weight to prevent encumbrance. This would be impossible with an indistinct pool.

#### Encounters

There's at least one encounter in which the amount of gold on each present character has a measurable impact on the outcome and difficulty of the confrontation. Those encounters would break if you just had a nebulous pool.

### Manual work makes it... achievable

To stack all gold on only one character, manual work is required:

- Only loot with one character, and distribute any non-gold for weight onto other characters after the loot session.
- Sort the inventory by type after looting

Comment: There's also another pretty major reason why gold works this way! Gold has **weight**, and counts towards encumbrance. Its why your barbarians make better treasure mules than your rogues and wizards!

Comment: If you're in single player it doesn't really matter which characters have your gold anyway, when you're at a vendor in barter mode you can click the balance button a few times and it will pull gold from other characters to add to the trade.